# How to deal with types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I've started learning Haskell and I've been reading "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good". I read up to halfway through the Modules chapter. A friend showed me codewars and I decided to put some of what I've learnt to the test.

I am trying to make a function which returns a Boolean of whether the given Integral is a power of 4. Here is the code.

```
module PowerOfFour where

isWhole n = fromIntegral (round n) == n

isPowerOf4 :: Integral n => n -> Bool
isPowerOf4 4 = True
isPowerOf4 x = if x < 4 then
    False
else
    if isWhole (x / 4) then
    isPowerOf4 (truncate (x / 4))
  else
    False
```

This is the error message I get.

```
/tmp/haskell11524-8-kke52v/PowerOfFour.hs:10:12:
    Could not deduce (RealFrac n) arising from a use of `isWhole'
    from the context (Integral n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 isPowerOf4 :: Integral n => n -> Bool
      at /tmp/haskell11524-8-kke52v/PowerOfFour.hs:5:15-37
    Possible fix:
      add (RealFrac n) to the context of
        the type signature for isPowerOf4 :: Integral n => n -> Bool
    In the expression: isWhole (x / 4)
    In the expression:
      if isWhole (x / 4) then isPowerOf4 (truncate (x / 4)) else False
    In the expression:
      if x < 4 then
          False
      else
          if isWhole (x / 4) then isPowerOf4 (truncate (x / 4)) else False

/tmp/haskell11524-8-kke52v/PowerOfFour.hs:10:23:
    Could not deduce (Fractional n) arising from a use of `/'
    from the context (Integral n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 isPowerOf4 :: Integral n => n -> Bool
      at /tmp/haskell11524-8-kke52v/PowerOfFour.hs:5:15-37
    Possible fix:
      add (Fractional n) to the context of
        the type signature for isPowerOf4 :: Integral n => n -> Bool
    In the first argument of `isWhole', namely `(x / 4)'
    In the expression: isWhole (x / 4)
    In the expression:
      if isWhole (x / 4) then isPowerOf4 (truncate (x / 4)) else False
```

What am I doing wrong?

I used fromIntegral in isWhole to fix a similar error and isWhole now works fine individually. However, I can't seem to get rid of these errors in isPowerOf4. I've tried the possible fixes GHC provides, but I probably wasn't doing it right.

I'd rather keep the type signature of the isPowerOf4 function, as that is provided by codewars, so I'm guessing it's a requirement.

Comment: Your function's argument is an instance of `Integral`, but the `/` operator expects an instance of `Fractional`:  `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`. You want to use integer-division operator instead: `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`.

Comment: @Jubobs: that doesn't make sense, as the OP wants to `isWhole`-test the result. Wouldn't be very interesting for `Integral a`, would it?

Comment: None of the solutions in these answers work, so I can't accept them. I would like to up vote, but I don't have enough reputation.

It's ~8 am here, so I have to go back to my nice comfortable Ruby job for now, but I'll respond in more detail as soon as I get back.

Comment: @leftaroundabout My comment was *not* meant as a full answer. I was merely explaining one of the type errors.

Comment: @habibalamin Could you explain where you have problems with the given answers. For me they all work.

Comment: @bmaderbacher okay, just got back from work. So, I just tried it again and it turns out the codewars test require `isPowerOf4 0` to return `True`. I tried adding a line

`isPowerOf4 0 = True` before the `isPowerOf4 x` line and it didn't work. It still fails the test. Apart from that, the function works in my eyes, so I'm going to accept Jeremy List's answer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, "Wouldn't be very interesting for Integral a, would it?"

Haha, I just realised how dumb that was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell the `/` operator is for fractional types not integral ones. For integral types you should use `div` (you can use it infix by surrounding it in backticks). You can also use `mod` or `rem` to find the remainder, like `%` in typical languages (they are different for negative numbers)

```
isPowerOf4 :: Integral n => n -> Bool
isPowerOf4 4 = True
isPowerOf4 x = if x < 4
  then False
  else
    if x `mod` 4 == 0
      then isPowerOf4 (x `div` 4)
      else False
```

Comment: I knew about `mod` and `div` and I don't know why I didn't go down that path sooner.

The line `if isWhole (x / 4) then` was originally `if isWhole x then`, which is why it was less obvious (I was still working on the problem while asking the question, haha).

I still don't think I understand however, why my original solution didn't work anyway. AFAICS, `isWhole` works fine and… never mind, I'm an idiot.

Comment: I think the first sentence of my answer is the bit you weren't getting.

Answer (score 4):

As @leftaroundabout explained `/` is floating point division and the results may be object to rounding error. Therefore your is `isWhole` function is not guarantied to work correctly in all cases.

A better approach would be to use integer division and modulo, as suggested by @Jubobs.

`div` is integer division it gives you the result of a division with out the remainder. That's the same as you expect from `truncate (x / 4)`. This should be rewritten as `div x 4`, so it's not relying on floating point numbers.

For `isWhole` you can use modulo this is the rest of an integer division. (e.g. `mod 5 4 == 1`) If it is zero there is no remainder, the result is a whole number. Instead of `isWhole (x / 4)` you can use `mod x 4 == 0`. Both `div` and `mod` work exact so there is not danger of rounding errors.

Comment: It seems @JeremyList beaten me and posted his answer will I was still writing :)

Answer (score 3):

Haskell never, *ever* does implict type conversions. That may seem rather obdurate to most programmers, but actually it is one of the reasons why Haskell's type system works so great. Completely shunning conversions makes many things much simpler, and it's pretty prerequisite for full bidirectional type inference.

In your case, the problem is in `x / 4`. A division, and you seem expect the result to be possibly noninteger. But it *must* be integer, as long as it has an integral type<sup>1</sup>! So you need to explicitly convert to a fractional type<sup>2</sup> first. The simplest way is indeed the `fromIntegral` function you've already discovered:

```
   if isWhole $ fromIntegral x / 4 then ...
```

To make it clear: that's parsed as `if isWhole ( (fromIntegral x)/4 ) then`. At this point you may wonder: if I just said Haskell never implicitly converts stuff, then why is it fine to divide by the integer literal `4`? The answer to that is, Haskell doesn't have integer literals! It only has various *numeric literals*. A whole-number literal doesn't have any particular type, it is polymorphic (i.e., it requests from the context *what type is expected here*, and than behaves as that type – provided that the type is in the `Num` class).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>C “solves” this problem by making integer division trucate the result... which leads to a load of problems, probably more than you'd get with implicit conversion.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>“Some fractional type” means, in Haskell, it'll default to `Double`. That type is very fast, but it's also not entirely unproblematic because floating-point numbers are inherently inexact. I'm not sure right now if this would be a problem in your application; because of the `==` comparison it might well be. Basically, you need to specify the type of `isWhole` to prevent that, as `isWhole :: Rational -> Bool`. The `Rational` type represents noninteger numbers as exact fractions.</sub>

Comment: As others note, using `rem` makes a lot more sense here. Another option is to use something from `Data.Bits`.

Comment: @dfeuer Your suggestion (using `Data.Bits`) seems like the best approach. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @Jubobs, because I haven't looked over the assembly yet to see if they're any different in the end, and I'm not sure I want to take the time. GHC does attempt to optimize division by powers of two, although it is otherwise very stupid about division.